# How do I detect the ID of a button using Javascript in IE and Safari?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer, safari

In my code, I have a directive, which has `on-blur = blurFunc($event)`.

Suppose I click on a button that has `id = "myButton"' and is outside of the directive.  I need to know which button I clicked in the`blurFunc` method.

In Chrome: `$event.relatedTarget.id` equals `myButton`.

In FF: `$event.rangeParent.id` equals `myButton`.

I'm looking for a way to get the button id in IE10 and Safari.  How do I do that?

Comment: Works on IE10, but not on Safari :(
Any ideas for Safari?

Comment: When I try to use setTimeout, the ng-blur override the ng-click and the click is not called. when I change it to ng-mousedown, the ng-blur is not called (I want to update a value on click on the button and then use it on blur)

Comment: Solved by using onClick (updating a flag) and then onBlur (Checking the flag). It's weird there is no native solution for Safari...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.event.srcElement.id` to get the id of the button inside the `blur` event. For example:

```
$("#idtesting").blur(function(e){
    console.log("Id: " + window.event.srcElement.id);
});
```

Comment: Nope. secElement has the directive I blured out from and not the button I clicked on.